# Efficient path update for large tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to find the most tensorflow efficient way to perform a path dependent update on a large tensor (>200 rows and columns).

The solution needs to be differentiable (and potentially xla compatible)

I'm currently using tf.unstack, examining each tensor in a for loop and using tf.where to filter out the condition I want. This is quite slow and results in many tensor operations

```py
Bt = tf.ones([256])
Bt_n = tf.random_normal([200,256]) # would actually be calculated elsewhere
Mr = tf.random_normal([200,256])
Mp = tf.random_normal([200,256])

total = [Bt]

for mr, mp, n_Bt in zip(tf.unstack(Mr), 
                      tf.unstack(Mp),                                                      
                      tf.unstack(Bt_n)):
    Bt = tf.where(tf.logical_or(Bt <= mr, Bt >= mp), n_Bt, Bt)
    total.append(Bt)

final = tf.concat(total, axis=0)
```

Just looking for the most efficient (fewest ops needed) way to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: How is the above code working for you. I tried and received error while trying to run the program: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Inputs to operation Select of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [1,256] != input 1: [256] [Op:Select]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - i needed to use tf.scan

ie.

```py
tf.scan(lambda a, x: tf.where(tf.logical_or(a <= x[0], a >= x[1]), x[2], a) , [Mr,Mp,Bt_n], initializer = Bt)
```